# Linux -> C++ code : Object Serialization

Tags: c++, xml, serialization

What library should I use for an object serialization that is the input for an .net webservice (meaning that this webservice needs an xml at its input)?

*As a further question:*

If using Non Intrusive Version (Boot Serialization), when writing in the xml file what is the exactly code? (`oa<<` ?). I've tried some solutions but it seems I have error. I can't actually say `oa<< g.` .

Here is the code:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class gps_position
{
public:
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
    gps_position(){};
};

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, gps_position & g, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & g.degrees;
        ar & g.minutes;
        ar & g.seconds;
    }    

} } // namespace boost::serialization

// gps_position g;

int main() {

    gps_position obj;
    std::ofstream ofs("filename2.xml");

    if(ofs.good()) {
        //const gps_position g;

        try {
            boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);

            // what to write in the xml?
            oa << ??????????????????;

        } catch(boost::archive::archive_exception& ex) {

        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @mely use proper tags for your questions: the better your questions are tagged, the more chances you have for them to be seen.

Comment: Are you sure you just want serialization - and not a complete C++ SOAP toolkit?

Comment: @mely: it's not enough to generate "an xml". It has to conform to whatever format the webservice expects (most likely some kind of SOAP)

Comment: @mely - Just a friendly piece of advice: Please don't use answers to ask further questions about the problem you're trying to solve. Update your question instead or ask in a comment of you need some minor clarification. Doing this will cause you to lose reputation as it's viewed as poor site etiquette.

Answer (score 3):

[Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) will serialize C++ objects into an XML stream. I don't know if it will automatically be compatible with your webservice or not though.

**Answer to comment:**
Here is an example:

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp> 
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp> 
#include <fstream>

class myclass
{
    //...
private: 
    int var1;
    double var2;
    std::vector<int> var3;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(var1);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(var2);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(var3); 
    }
};

//...

myclass myobject;

//...

ofstream ofs("filename.xml");
if(ofs.good()) {
    try {
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(myobject);
    }catch(boost::archive::archive_exception& ex){
        //...
    }
}
```

Basically inside your class you need to make `boost::serialization::access` a friend and provide the member function `serialize`.  Some tricks are played here with overloading the `&` operator to act as a stream operator in different directions depending on whether you are saving or loading.  For most classes, just follow this pattern though for all the member variables and don't worry about what is actually happening (read the docs if you want to know).

To actually serialize the object, you just stream it to an `xml_oarchive` object that can be instantiated to write to any `ostream` object.

Comment: can you give me a short example? If I have:

Comment: MyClass{ std::string name; int i; } *cls;

Comment: how will I serialize for example cls->name = "monday";

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested , then you can have a look at protocol buffers by Google. The documentation is also pretty good for the same :
[Here](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/cpptutorial.html)

And its performance is much better than XML.

Answer (score 0):

How do I compile the example you have about Boost Serialization?

`g++ example.cpp -o example++`

returns a lot of errors (on Linux: Ubuntu 10.10)

I found the result:

`g++ example.cpp -lboost_serialization`

Comment: g++ -I <path to boost> -c example.cpp
<p>
g++ -L <path to boost libs> -lboost_filesystem -o example.o
</p>

Comment: Also you must consider adding the path of your boost lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH / LD_LIBRARY_PATH64 (for 32bit/64bit arch) environment variable

Comment: thx..and what about non intrusive version? in the main how to add the elements in the xml file? An example of my code is the one with gps_position written above. Have a great day